# Cant connect jupyterhub to keycloak and getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, vagrant, keycloak, jupyterhub

I'm trying to set up jupyterhub on vagrant, but after I connected (I think) the authentication to keycloak, I got the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error in my browser, after clicking the oauth2 button.
Is it problem with my jupyterhub_config.py or wrong oauth_callback_url?

My keycloak init:

```
cd $KEYCLOAK_PATH/bin && sudo bash add-user-keycloak.sh -u admin -p admin
cd $KEYCLOAK_PATH/bin && sudo nohup ./standalone.sh -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 > $KEYCLOAK_LOGS/keycloak.log 2>&1 &
```

My jupyterhub_config.py:

```
c.Authenticator.admin_users = {'vagrant'}
from oauthenticator.generic import GenericOAuthenticator
c.JupyterHub.authenticator_class = GenericOAuthenticator
c.GenericOAuthenticator.oauth_callback_url = 'http://0.0.0.0:8180/auth/realms/testrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth'
c.GenericOAuthenticator.client_id = 'oauth-secret'
c.GenericOAuthenticator.client_secret = ''
c.GenericOAuthenticator.token_url = 'http://0.0.0.0:8180/auth/realms/testrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token'
c.GenericOAuthenticator.userdata_url = 'http://0.0.0.0:8180/auth/realms/testrealm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo'
```

Forwarded ports from Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8001, host: 8001
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8081, host: 8081
```

Some of the redirects:

```
[I 2020-10-23 08:25:51.287 JupyterHub oauth2:103] OAuth redirect: 'http://0.0.0.0:8180/auth/realms/testrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth'
[I 2020-10-23 08:25:51.290 JupyterHub log:174] 302 GET /hub/oauth_login?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A8180%2Fauth%2Frealms%2Ftestrealm%2Fprotocol%2Fopenid-connect%2Fauth&client_id=oauth-secret&state=[secret] -> ?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A8180%2Fauth%2Frealms%2Ftestrealm%2Fprotocol%2Fopenid-connect%2Fauth&client_id=oauth-secret&state=[secret] (@10.0.2.2) 3.66ms
[I 2020-10-23 08:25:51.307 JupyterHub oauth2:103] OAuth redirect: 'http://0.0.0.0:8180/auth/realms/testrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth'
[I 2020-10-23 08:25:51.311 JupyterHub log:174] 302 GET /hub/oauth_login?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A8180%2Fauth%2Frealms%2Ftestrealm%2Fprotocol%2Fopenid-connect%2Fauth&client_id=oauth-secret&state=[secret] -> ?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A8180%2Fauth%2Frealms%2Ftestrealm%2Fprotocol%2Fopenid-connect%2Fauth&client_id=oauth-secret&state=[secret] (@10.0.2.2) 4.66ms
[I 2020-10-23 08:25:51.326 JupyterHub oauth2:103] OAuth redirect: 'http://0.0.0.0:8180/auth/realms/testrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth'
[I 2020-10-23 08:25:51.329 JupyterHub log:174] 302 GET /hub/oauth_login?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A8180%2Fauth%2Frealms%2Ftestrealm%2Fprotocol%2Fopenid-connect%2Fauth&client_id=oauth-secret&state=[secret] -> ?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A8180%2Fauth%2Frealms%2Ftestrealm%2Fprotocol%2Fopenid-connect%2Fauth&client_id=oauth-secret&state=[secret] (@10.0.2.2) 4.80ms
```

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: Set the `OAUTH2_AUTHORIZE_URL` and `OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL` environment variables to the appropriate URLs which you can find in your identity provider (i.e. KeyCloak).

I've been scratching my head with this one for a bit... As you see on your own logs, JupyterHub somehow believes it is the one responsible for authenticating a user *but* it also says that, after authentication, the user should be redirected back to itself (that's what the `oauth_callback_url` is saying). This leads to the JupyterHub server calling itself in a recursive way until the browser gives up.

I assume you are running both *keyCloak* and *JupyterHub* on the same VM, which you provisioned with *vagrant*. If that's the case, consider changing the `0.0.0.0` bits with `127.0.0.1`. Otherwise, try to change `0.0.0.0` to the IPv4 address where KeyCloak can be reached for `c.GenericOAuthenticator.userdata_url` and `c.GenericOAuthenticator.token_url`.  When things aren't working as they should it's usually a good idea to avoid wildcards and the like to narrow down where the problem lies...

The address where the JupyterHub instance lives should be included for `c.GenericOAuthenticator.oauth_callback_url` and, on top of that, you should point it back to the JupyterHub instance. In my case, that would be `<jupyterhub-ip>:<jupyterhub-port>/hub/oauth_callback`. Remember that this member is telling KeyCloak where it should contact JupyterHub during the authentication flow.

In any case, the *only* thing for us to do is point JupyterHub to the KeyCloak instance. If you take a look at [this snippet](https://github.com/jupyterhub/oauthenticator/blob/ba44fdeee67db29e9decf6eea08aa1c0d929621d/oauthenticator/oauth2.py#L263-L269) from JupyterHub's OAuthenticator, you'll find that the default value for the `authorize_url` is extracted from an environment variable named `OAUTH2_AUTHORIZE_URL`. I'm not really confident on what the `@default` decorator does, but I do now that manually setting the value of `authorize_url` in the configuration file didn't work for me...

You just need to export the aforementioned environment value and that should be the end of it. You can do so with:

```sh
export OAUTH2_AUTHORIZE_URL="https://<keycloak-ip>:<keycloak-port>auth/realms/testrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth"
```

I have also exported the token url through the `OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL` variable in pretty much the same way, with a value equivalent to what you have in your configuration (once you change the `0.0.0.0` IP address). The [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jupyterhub/oauthenticator/issues/107) that helped me

Make sure these variable are visible to the JupyterHub process. I was running *The Littlest JupyterHub* and I had to include them in the appropriate unit file (`/etc/systemd/system/jupyterhub.service`) like below:

```sh
Environment=OAUTH2_AUTHORIZE_URL=https://<keycloak-ip>:<keycloak-port>/auth/realms/<realm-name>/protocol/openid-connect/auth
Environment=OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL=https://<keycloak-ip>:<keycloak-port>/auth/realms/<realm-name>/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

Remember to run `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl restart jupyterlab` if that's your scenario...

Coming now to an end, the key idea is to set the appropriate environment variables so that things behave as they should...

P.D: I might be missing something with the `@default` decorator, but I would rather set an environment variable than get down to brass tacks with python for this kind of issue...

If you have any further questions feel free to fire away!

[Source](https://github.com/jupyterhub/oauthenticator/issues/107).